# Using global state in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In my current Asp.Net application I am finding a number core services that are slowly spreading throughout the application through the use of Dependency Injection. One of those services is the need to know who the current authenticated user is. I have a UserService that encapsulates the logic for getting the CurrentUser, but it seems like I am injecting this same service almost everywhere in my application. Is there a different method I could be using for accessing this Global service without constantly growing my constructors to inject yet another object into my classes? (of course I still want to maintain testability)

Comment: It might help to include relevant code and clarify what is the actual problem -- you're hoping for one line of code rather than 3?

Comment: No. I am concerned that my constructors are growing quite large, and mostly from injecting all of these cross cutting concerns - Users, Configuration, Logging, Security, etc.
As for relevant code, it is a constructor... I shouldn't really need to specify what a constructor looks like - it takes in a dependency and stores it in an instance member.  No logic or anything that would provide you any more context than what I have already stated.

Comment: Maybe you can inject IServiceProvider and get the required service where you need so your constructors are not grow. I'm not sure that you want but hope it helps.